# two lines to one line in command output, can I freeze FH?

Tags: perl

I want to store this output, see below, in a filehandle or something other than a file on the server.
Can I freeze it, then split on desired fields, or? Kindly accepting advice!  The raw output is **two** lines per record, the script output is **one** line per record and therein the latter lies the problem.  I cannot split certain fileds when there are **two** lines per record.  For example I do not want any line that contains 'root S_PASWD_READ', so I attempt a split on fields 8 and 10, but with two lines this is obviously not working.  Thank you!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stream = qq(/data/auditpr/stream.out);
my @tmp;


open my $FH, "+<", $stream or die $!;

while ((my $ln = <$FH>)) {
    $ln =~ s/\-+//g;
    $ln =~ s/\n/ / unless $a++ % 2;  ## MAKE IT PRETTY 1 LINE.
    #push @tmp, split(/\s+/, $ln);
}
```

__Script_OUTPUT__1LINE

Wed Jan 15 15:56:21 2020 5308742  2949626  root     stopsrc                         S_PASWD_READ    OK                    audit object read event detected /etc/security/passwd

__RAW_OUTPUT__2LINES

Wed Jan 15 15:56:21 2020 5308744  2949626  root     stopsrc                         S_PASWD_READ    OK

```
     audit object read event detected /etc/security/passwd
```

Comment: You can simply read another line from `$FH` to get the second line, if you are sure it will always be in pairs. `my $second_line = <$FH> // die "Didn't get a second line";`

Comment: Reading the code, I was really confused by `$l` (lowercase L), which I have mistaken it as `$1` (one).

As @Grinnz suggested, you can read another line, even with:

`while ((my $line1 = read($FH)) && (my $line2 = read($FH))) {`

Comment: the second line is not important until after a line NOT containing string 'root S_PASWD_READ' is found, which then I'd like the output to be printed on one line.

Comment: here is an awk example:

awk '
!($8 =="root" && $10 ==S_PASWD_READ)
END {print "\t\t\t\t--- end of report ---"}' localfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this (this is not a complete script only focusing on your question)

```
my @output ;
while ( my $line = <$FH> ) {
   chomp $line ;
   if ( my $line2 = <$FH> ) { 
      chomp $line2 ;
      $line .= " $line2" ; 
   }

   push @output, $line ;
}
```

Now you can search through @output which contains 1 line format only. This also works if the input ends in the middle of a two line segment (although obviously you can't search on data that isn't there).

```
while my $search (@output) {
    my @fields = split(' ',$search) ; 
    if ( $fields[8] =~ m/something/ and $fields[10] =~ m/something/) { next } ;  # skip lines you don't want
    # do something here with the output
}
```

Comment: `$line =~ s/\n//;` can also be written `chomp $line;`